What is the purpose of plaintext padding before encoding it into a elliptic curve point over a finite field in an EC ElGamal?
In EC ElGamal the encryption flow for a plaintext is well-known and clear, and for encoding a plaintext into an elliptic curve point over a finite field I use the following strategy:

Take the size of a curve field, then, allocating additional safety bits, I create a byte slice as $padding \| msg$, which is the exact of a curve field size.
Then I use the Weierstrass equation to find a quadratic residue for $Y$ value.
Then I create EC ElGamal ciphertext using a well-known algorithm.

My question is - what will happen if I don't pad a plaintext before encoding it into an elliptic curve point over a finite field? What kind of attacks could be performed on an EC ElGamal ciphertext, if plaintext wasn't padded? I would like to see a crypto paper on that topic, which confirms that such attacks can be performed and also examples of it.
